# plot with pgfplots two horizontal labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis

I want to produce the following plot:

[image: lorentzian]

Is a Lorentzian function, centered at x=408. But notice the upper label in the frame, that indicates a wave number associated to the coordinate measured in pixels (the bottom label).

I came across a few questions regarding plotting two x axes in pgfplots. (For example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/how-can-i-use-two-x-axes-in-pgfplots) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/pgfplots-legends-in-multiple-y-axis-plot-overlapping)), but they all are concerned about plotting **two** functions or curves on the same plot, and labeling them differently. I have only one function that I want to label twice.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
xlabel={CCD coordinate [px]},
ylabel={Intensity [A.U]},
xmin=0,xmax=1000,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
]
\addplot[line width=1pt,samples=500,domain=0:1000]{4.278*10^(7)/((x-408.4)^2+54.25^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the upper label to consist the following markers, written in the form

{{x<sub>1</sub>,label<sub>1</sub>},{x<sub>2</sub>,label<sub>2</sub>}, ... }

```
{80.15,639.892},{244.225,648.096},{408.3,656.3},{572.375,664.504},{736.45,672.708},{900.525,680.911}
```

What option should I add to my code to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also needed this plot in the past, so here is my result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.17,
    % create a style for the plot, so you don't need to repeat yourself
    % in both `axis` environments.
    Lorentzian plot style/.style={
        every tick label/.append style={font=\small},
        scaled y ticks=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1000,
        % keep `domain` limits in sync with the x-axis limits
        domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            % load the above created style
            Lorentzian plot style,
            xlabel={CCD coordinate [px]},
            ylabel={Intensity [a.u.]},
            axis x line*=left,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            ]
            \addplot[
            line width=1pt,
            samples=501,
            ] {4.278e7/((x - 408.4)^2 + 54.25^2)};
        \end{axis}
        
        % produce top x-axis
        \begin{axis}[
            % load the above created style here too
            Lorentzian plot style,
            xlabel={Wavelength [nm]},
            axis x line*=right,
            xtick={80.15,244.225,408.3,572.375,736.45,900.525},
            xticklabels={639.9,648.1,656.3,664.5,672.7,680.9},
            ytick=\empty,
            ]
            \addplot[
            draw=none,
            % for dummy use minimum number of `samples`
            samples=2 
            % dummy function to make it as less computational expensive as possible
            ]{0};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First, I removed the right x axis of the main plot using `axis x line*=left` and then I added the same plot, but did not draw it with `draw=none`, added the right x axis using `axis x line*=right` and your labels with `xtick={...}` and `xticklabels={...}`, and at the end removed the y axis and labels of the empty plot using `ytick=\empty`.

Then, I recognised some overlap of the y label scaling factor, so I removed it using `scaled y ticks=false` and also decreased the size of the x axis labels using `every tick label/.append style={font=\small}`.

Hopefully, it suits your needs.

**EDIT**

I added @Stefan Pinnows excellent suggestions for improving the workflow and placed some of his comments for better understanding the changes.

Comment: For the y label the unit should be a.u. (arbitrary unit), or am I wrong?

Comment: +1 You were absolutely right to add a second `axis` and state corresponding `xtick`s and corresponding `xticklabels`. But there is room for a bit of improvement to your answer. Since this would be a bit too long for a comment, I posted it as separate answer. Please have a look if you find some useful stuff there. If you would adapt these stuff in your answer, I'll be happy to delete mine.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for your improvements. My answer was me trying to solve the problem years ago when I started with pgfplots. I will integrate your suggestions for less code and faster processing.

Comment: I improved the comments a bit ...