# Unwanted stretch and translation of an additional axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

%% 1st and 2nd waveforms
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
    ylabel={Current [\si{\A}]},
    grid=major
]
\addplot [blue, line width = 1, smooth] 
table[x=t,y=ch1,col sep=comma]{myDataFile.csv};
\addplot [green, line width = 1, smooth] 
table[x=t,y=ch2,col sep=comma]{myDataFile.csv};
\end{axis}
%% Here starts the 3rd waveform
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
    ylabel={Voltage (Normalised)}
    %grid=major
]
\addplot [red, line width = 1, smooth]
table[x=t,y=ch3,col sep=comma]{myDataFile.csv};
\end{axis}
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `myDataFile.csv` file is the following:

```
%myDataFile.csv%
t,ch1,ch2,ch3
-4,-2,0.0625,0.756
-3,-1.5,0.125,-0.141
-2,-1,0.25,-0.909
-1,-0.5,0.5,-0.841
0,0,1,0
1,0.5,2,0.841
2,1,4,0.909
3,1.5,8,0.141
4,2,16,-0.758
```

The thing is that the 3rd waveform is translated (up about 6 units) and also stretched, so that it extends the whole vertical span determined by the minimum value of `ch1` or `ch2`, the smaller of the two, and the maximum value of `ch1` or `ch2`, the larger of the two.

In the example above, `ch3` (red) is a sine function plotted from t=-4 to t=+4, so it is bounded from -1 to 1 in the vertical direction. As you can see, it is not plotted correctly. (`ch1` is `y=-t/2`, and `ch2` is `2^t`)

[image]

I am following the code in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41011/180429) answer, about plotting two functions on one "canvas".

From what I see in the inline picture of this linked answer, the same effect applies there too.

How can I avoid this and plot `ch3` as it is?

To elucidate my point, I want something that looks like the following (plotted in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)):

[image: Desired output]

Notice how the sine wave spans in the vertical direction compared with the `2^t` curve. It is really from -1 to +1 and its "x-axis" coincides with that of the other two curves. But, it describes a different physical quantity and therefore "deserves" a different label and ticks, to be plotted on the right edge.

Moreover, how can I instruct `pgfplots` to stretch it in the vertical direction by, say, 2 times each value entry? I found a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134730/how-to-scale-existing-coordinates-data-in-pgfplots) about scaling a data set, but I don't know how to do it for data imported from a `csv` file as in the case here.

Comment: Regarding scaling, the same method as Jake's second suggestion works for files as well. With `\addplot table` you can provide the table either as a filename, or directly in the `.tex` file as in Jake's example, but `y expr=\thisrow{column name}*10` works for both.

Comment: I honestly don't quite understand what you mean about the stretching and translation. The sine function looks a bit odd because you have very few sample points and you use `smooth`. If it should be a pure sine function, you can always do `\addplot [blue, domain=-4:4,samples=50] {sin(deg(x))};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't want to add an anonymous function (such as `sin(deg(x))`), I need to plot data exported from an oscilloscope. And I uploaded an additional image together with an explanation so I hope the readers can now better understand my question. And thanks for the code snippet about scaling the numerical entries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the y-limits to the same values for both axes, so add `ymin=-4, ymax=17`. There are several ways to do that, you can add it to both axes separately, you can do `\pgfplotsset{common axis settings/.style={ymin=-4, ymax=17}}` and then add `common axis settings` to both `axis` options, or simply add `\pgfplotsset{ymin=-4, ymax=17}` between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and the first `\begin{axis}`.

I'd probably remove `smooth`, which will use bezier curves between sample points instead of straight lines, and the x-ticks and label from the second axis (which currently are duplicated).

As mentioned in the comment, you can use the method for scaling plots described by Jake in the answer you link to, I demonstrated that in code below as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  ymin=-4,
  ymax=17,
  every axis plot/.append style={
    line width = 1,
    % if you want to add markers as in the Desmos plot, uncomment this
%      mark=*,
%      mark size=2
     }
  }
%% 1st and 2nd waveforms
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
    ylabel={Current [\si{\A}]},
    grid=major
]
\addplot [blue] table[x=t,y=ch1,col sep=comma] {myDataFile.csv};
\addplot [green] table[x=t,y=ch2,col sep=comma] {myDataFile.csv};
\end{axis}

%% Here starts the 3rd waveform
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xtick=\empty,
%    xlabel={Time [\si{s}]},
    ylabel={Voltage (Normalised)},
    ylabel style={red}
]
\addplot [red] table[x=t,y=ch3,col sep=comma] {myDataFile.csv};
\addplot [red, densely dashed] table[x=t,y expr=\thisrow{ch3}*2,col sep=comma] {myDataFile.csv};
\end{axis}
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to find those values automatically, but it's too late in the evening for me to try right now :)

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Could you help me, in a comment, and write down a setting to change the x-to-y ratio for these two plot? I want it be something like 1-to-3 height to width aspect ratio, and not the default 1-to-1.

Comment: @tush e.g. `width=8cm, height=5cm` in the pgfplotsset?

Comment: Yes, something like this, but the output was clipped from the top.

Comment: @tush I don't understand, changing the size of the axis shouldn't introduce any clipping. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123012/discussion-between-tush-and-torbjorn-t).