# Bell curve with multiple x-axes and annotations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I've just started working with `pgfplots` and I'm getting good results, but I'm having difficulties getting this one done in LaTeX:

[image: Bell curve with multiple x-axes and annotations]

The curve itself is not a problem, but the multiple x-axes (I don't need the top one, just the middle and the bottom ones) and especially the "68.2%" right in the middle of the plot just won't work.

**Here's what I got so far:**

[image: My try]

```
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
      hide y axis, tick align=outside,
      domain=-3:3, samples=50,
      axis lines*=left, xlabel=$IQ-Werte$, ylabel=$~$,
      height=5cm, width=13cm,
      xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2}, ytick=\empty,
      xticklabels={%
        $70$,
        $85$,
        $100$,
        $115$,
        $130$}      
      ]

      \addplot [thick,black!50!black] {gauss(0,1)};
      \addplot [fill=black!10, domain=-1:1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: Have a look at [Christian's answer to this question about multiple y-axes on the same plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27477/1402) and adapt.

Longer answer: keep in mind that a pgfplots `axis` environment just a special type of `tikz` node.  It has special coordinate systems, and a useful one for drawing over the the plot is the one called `axis cs`.  With this coordinate system you can place TikZ drawing commands on any part of the plot window.

You can achieve a second x-axis by making a second axis environment with the same specifications but no actual function plotted, shifted appropriately.  If there were a function plotted it would overlap the first, but without a function all you see are the axes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{icomma}
\begin{document}
   \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
      \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
   }
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      % options common to all axes here
      \pgfplotsset{
         axis x line*=middle, 
         hide y axis, 
         tick align=outside,
         ytick=\empty,
         xmin=-3,xmax=3,
         width=13cm,height=7cm,
         xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},      
      }

   % main plot
   \begin{axis}[
      samples=50,
      xlabel={IQ-Werte},
      domain=-3:3, 
      xticklabels={%
         $70$,
         $85$,
         $100$,
         $115$,
         $130$}      
      ]
      \addplot [thick,fill=blue!10,domain=-3.1:3.1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
      \addplot [fill=blue!20, domain=-1:1] {gauss(0,1)} \closedcycle;
      \draw[thick,arrows={<->}] (axis cs:-1,0.125) -- (axis cs:1,0.125)
         node[pos=0.5,above] {$68,2\%$};
    \end{axis}

    % extra x axis
    \begin{axis}[yshift=-1.5cm,
      xlabel={Prozentr\"ange},
      xticklabels={{$2,3$}, {$15,9$}, {$50$}, {$84,1$}, {$97,7$}}
    ]
    \addplot[draw=none]{1};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Notes:

- The [`icomma`](http://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) package allows for comma decimal separators like you used.  You might be implementing that with a different package.
- You used `$IQ-Werte$` for the x axis label, but that sets the text within math mode.  This means the font shape comes out math italic, there are no ligatures, and the hyphen becomes a minus sign.  You probably just want the plain text.  Use `\textit{IQ-Werte}` if you want italic.
- One hack I needed to ensure that the ticks plotted in the second `axis` were noticed: I  plotted a constant function and made it invisible with the `draw=none` key.
- An earlier version had some white space between the axis and the first plot, as noticed by @maetra.  I fixed this by making it a `\closedcycle`, then extending the domain slightly so that the resulting vertical edges are clipped by the `xmin:xmax` window.

Comment: I see I spelled *Prozentränge* wrong.  Entschuldigen Sie mir.

Comment: Seems like the filling of the outer plot does not continue until the first axis.

Comment: @maetra: Thanks.  fixed.  (along with my spelling error.)

Comment: You, Sir, are fantastic -- thanks a lot! This works like a charm.

Comment: @Daniel: Your upvote and check are thanks enough. :-)