# Multiple Y-axis plot (4 Ys YY-YY)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can someone help me creat a figure like the attached one which is generated by Origin Lab?

[image]

According to Jack's suggestion, I made my tex code as follows. The last thing I have to complish is the legend. Even though Jack has told the way, I still do not know to how to make this legend out.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}


\begin{tikzpicture}
% f1
\begin{axis}[
color=black,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
xlabel={$y$},
ymin=1,
ymax=2,
ytick={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0},
yticklabels={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0},
y axis line style={blue},
ytick style={blue},
yticklabel style={blue},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
tick align = outside,]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1.09754040499941\\
2 1.12698681629351\\
3 1.14188633862722\\
4 1.15761308167755\\
5 1.27849821886705\\
6 1.42176128262627\\
7 1.48537564872284\\
8 1.54688151920498\\
9 1.63235924622541\\
10 1.79220732955955\\
11 1.8002804688888\\
12 1.81472368639318\\
13 1.90579193707562\\
14 1.91337585613902\\
15 1.91573552518907\\
16 1.95716694824295\\
17 1.9575068354343\\
18 1.9594924263929\\
19 1.96488853519928\\
20 1.97059278176062\\};
\end{axis}
% f2
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor2,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=2,
ymax=3,
ytick={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0},
yticklabels={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=left,
ylabel={$x$},
ylabel style=black,
hide x axis,
tick align =outside,]
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=-1.5cm} }
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 2.03183284637742\\
2 2.03444608050291\\
3 2.03571167857419\\
4 2.04617139063115\\
5 2.09713178123585\\
6 2.17118668781156\\
7 2.27692298496089\\
8 2.31709948006086\\
9 2.39222701953417\\
10 2.65547789017756\\
11 2.65574069915659\\
12 2.67873515485777\\
13 2.69482862297582\\
14 2.70604608801961\\
15 2.74313246812492\\
16 2.75774013057833\\
17 2.82345782832729\\
18 2.84912930586878\\
19 2.93399324775755\\
20 2.95022204883836\\};
\end{axis}
% f3
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor1,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=3,
ymax=4,
ytick={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0},
yticklabels={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0},
ytick style={mycolor1},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis,
tick align = outside,]
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 3.11899768155838\\
2 3.16261173519463\\
3 3.18687260455438\\
4 3.22381193949114\\
5 3.27602507699858\\
6 3.34038572666613\\
7 3.38155845709301\\
8 3.4387443596564\\
9 3.4455862007109\\
10 3.48976439578823\\
11 3.49836405198214\\
12 3.58526775097978\\
13 3.64631301011127\\
14 3.65509800397384\\
15 3.67970267685367\\
16 3.70936483085807\\
17 3.75468668198236\\
18 3.765516788149\\
19 3.79519990113706\\
20 3.95974395851608\\};
\end{axis}
% f4
\begin{axis}[
color=red,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=4,
ymax=5,
ytick={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0},
yticklabels={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis,
tick align = outside,]
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=1.5cm}}
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=red}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 4.13862444282868\\
2 4.14929400555906\\
3 4.19659525043121\\
4 4.24352496872499\\
5 4.25108385797603\\
6 4.25428217897153\\
7 4.25509511545927\\
8 4.25750825412374\\
9 4.34998376598481\\
10 4.47328884890273\\
11 4.50595705166514\\
12 4.5472155299638\\
13 4.61604467614664\\
14 4.69907672265669\\
15 4.75126705930565\\
16 4.81428482606882\\
17 4.84071725598366\\
18 4.8909032525358\\
19 4.92926362318723\\
20 4.95929142520544\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/drawing-curves-and-multiple-y-axes-in-one-plot-with-pgfplots

Comment: @Torbjørn I also have read the content available on the link： http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62291/can-i-draw-figure-3-y-axis-using-pgfplot  One problem that I confronted with is that I fail to specific the color of X and Y axises with different colors. You know that the these two links did not involve my case. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: 1. To get black labels, use `xlabel style=black` and `ylabel style=black`. 2. You're overwriting the `number format` definitions. Use `every y tick label/.prefix style={xshift=-1.5cm}`. 3. Use `tick style={blue}` 4. You'll have to add the legend images and entries manually, using `\addlegendimage{color=mycolor2,mark=*...}\addlegendentry{Y2}`. 5. Put something like `\pgfplotsset{width=9cm, height=6cm}` before the first plot.

Comment: @ Jake  According to your suggestion, I almost make it except the legend. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a single legend for different axes, you need to assemble the legend by saying `\addlegendimage{<plot options>} \addlegendentry{<legend text>}` once for each of your plots in the final axis.

You don't have to manually specify the `<plot options>`: Instead, you can put `\label{<plot name>}` directly after each of your `\addplot` commands. Then, you can simply say `\addlegendimage{refstyle=<plot name>}` to activate the plot styles.

[image]

(I also cleaned up your code a little bit)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}

\pgfplotstableread{
X   Y1          Y2          Y3          Y4
1   1.097540405 2.0318328464    3.1189976816    4.1386244428
2   1.1269868163    2.0344460805    3.1626117352    4.1492940056
3   1.1418863386    2.0357116786    3.1868726046    4.1965952504
4   1.1576130817    2.0461713906    3.2238119395    4.2435249687
5   1.2784982189    2.0971317812    3.276025077 4.251083858
6   1.4217612826    2.1711866878    3.3403857267    4.254282179
7   1.4853756487    2.276922985 3.3815584571    4.2550951155
8   1.5468815192    2.3170994801    3.4387443597    4.2575082541
9   1.6323592462    2.3922270195    3.4455862007    4.349983766
10  1.7922073296    2.6554778902    3.4897643958    4.4732888489
11  1.8002804689    2.6557406992    3.498364052 4.5059570517
12  1.8147236864    2.6787351549    3.585267751 4.54721553
13  1.9057919371    2.694828623 3.6463130101    4.6160446761
14  1.9133758561    2.706046088 3.655098004 4.6990767227
15  1.9157355252    2.7431324681    3.6797026769    4.7512670593
16  1.9571669482    2.7577401306    3.7093648309    4.8142848261
17  1.9575068354    2.8234578283    3.754686682 4.840717256
18  1.9594924264    2.8491293059    3.7655167881    4.8909032525
19  1.9648885352    2.9339932478    3.7951999011    4.9292636232
20  1.9705927818    2.9502220488    3.9597439585    4.9592914252
}\datatable

\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0.5, xmax=20.5,
    tick align = outside,
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% f1
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={1,...,20},
    xlabel={$y$},
    ymin=1, ymax=2,
    ytick={1.0,1.2,...,2.0},
    y axis line style={blue},
    ytick style={blue},
    yticklabel style=blue,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\addplot [
    color=blue,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt,
    mark size=2.7pt,
    mark=square*,
    mark options={solid}
] table [x=X, y=Y1]{\datatable};
\label{plot1} % So we can recall the plot style later on
\end{axis}
% f2
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor2,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=2,
ymax=3,
ytick={2.0,2.2,...,3.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=left,
ylabel={$x$},
ylabel style=black,
hide x axis,
every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=-1.5cm},
every tick/.style={xshift=-1.5cm},
every y tick label/.append style={xshift=-1.5cm}
]
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2}]
table [x=X, y=Y2]{\datatable};
\label{plot2}
\end{axis}
% f3
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor1,
scale only axis,
ymin=3,
ymax=4,
ytick={3.0,3.2,...,4.0},
ytick style={mycolor1},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis
]
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1}]
table [x=X, y=Y3]{\datatable};
\label{plot3}
\end{axis}

% f4
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=4,
ymax=5,
ytick={4.0,4.2,...,5.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis,
tick align = outside,
every outer y axis line/.style={
    red,
    xshift=1.5cm
},
every tick/.style={
    red,
    xshift=1.5cm
},
every y tick label/.append style={
    red,
    xshift=1.5cm
},
legend pos=north west
]

\addlegendimage{refstyle=plot1} \addlegendentry{Y1}
\addlegendimage{refstyle=plot2} \addlegendentry{Y2}
\addlegendimage{refstyle=plot3} \addlegendentry{Y3}

\addplot [
color=red,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=red}]
table [x=X, y=Y4]{\datatable};
\addlegendentry{Y4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of colour-blind viewers (also BW printing, projecting in bad light, etc.), I would suggest labelling the vertical scales with Y1…Y4.  The shapes distinguish the four plotted lines, but there’s currently no way apart from colour to match them up with their corresponding vertical scales.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Absolutely right. The axes need to be labelled with their units, too.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine  Can you give me an example using my data to  demonstrate what you said? I am not good at tex. Thanks!